# Getting the string version from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm getting an object from an ajax call, but I need the string instead. What should I do instead?

**file1:**

```
//some code...    

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: action,
data: { pictureID: pictureID, comment: comment },
error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
complete:function(data) {
document.getElementById(outputID).innerHTML = data;           
} //end of complete:function(data)
}); //end of $.ajax({
```

**file2:**

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

**output:**

```
[object Object]
```

**need output:**

```
test
```

Comment: Look at your network tab and verify what is being sent back.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Time to learn basic debugging in your favorite browser.  Most browsers open the debugging tools by hitting `F12` I believe.  I'm not being rude here -- but seriously -- if you are going to work in JavaScript learn the debugging tools and console.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Turns out that if I use success instead of complete, it prints out as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method from Complete to Success

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: action,
   data: { pictureID: pictureID, comment: comment },
   error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
   success:function(data) {
        document.getElementById(outputID).innerHTML = data;           
   } 
});
```

The first argument to the complete function is a jqXHR, not the response

Comment: It changed to undefined.

Comment: Do a console.log(data) instead of the innerHTML set and check the browser console, you should see the structure of the `data` object

Comment: Turns out that if I use success instead of complete, it prints out as a string.

Comment: Updated my answer for everyone else :)

Comment: You should explain **why** this fixes it: the first argument to the `complete` function is a `jqXHR`, not the response.